# Spring MVC: flash attribute vs model attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, attributes

What is the different between *flash* and *model* attribute?

I want to store an object and display it in my JSP as well as reuse it in other controller. I have use `sessionAttribute` and it works fine in the JSP, but the problem is when I try to retrieve that `model` attribute in other controller.

I lose some data. I searched around and found that `flash attribute` allows to past past value to different controller, doesn't it?

Answer (score 21):

If we want to pass the `attributes via redirect between two controllers`, we cannot use `request attributes` (they will not survive the redirect), and we cannot use Spring's `@SessionAttributes` (because of the way Spring handles it), only an ordinary `HttpSession` can be used, which is not very convenient.

**Flash attributes** provide a way for one request to store attributes intended for use in another. This is most commonly needed when redirecting — for example, the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. Flash attributes are saved temporarily before the redirect (typically in the session) to be made available to the request after the redirect and removed immediately.

Spring MVC has two main abstractions in support of flash attributes. `FlashMap` is used to hold flash attributes while `FlashMapManager` is used to store, retrieve, and manage `FlashMap` instances.

**Example**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView handleGet(Model model) {
    String some = (String) model.asMap().get("some");
    // do the job
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handlePost(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("some", "thing");

    return new ModelAndView().setViewName("redirect:/foo/bar");
  }

}
```

In above example, request comes to `handlePost`, `flashAttributes` are added, and retrieved in `handleGet` method.

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes) and [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-flash-attributes).

Comment: I am using almost same code, but for some reason my Model is not populated with the flashAttributes. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465326/spring-boot-redirectattributes-addflashattribute-not-preserving-the-value-in-the

Comment: "and we cannot use Spring's @SessionAttributes (because of the way Spring handles it)" -- Could you please kindly expand this part, especially the part inside the parentheses?