# How to pass redirect query parameter not in URL but hidden to Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my controller I am redirecting a model Attribute because I do not want it to be visible in Url. 
The problem now is another controller also redirects to this url but he does not add this flash attribute. Now I get a init  Method does not exist ( I do not remember the exact error message ) exception. What can I do.  Of course I can redirect with the paramter in the Url but then it is visible in the URL and could couse maybe some problems.

Comment: show us some of you code please (edit your post), so we can better help you. What exactly is the exception and where does it happen?

Comment: return "redirect:/someUrl?isNewImport=true;     isNewImport should be hidden. But now it is in Url. I do not want this

Comment: If you want the URL parameter to be hidden, you need to use **flash attributes**. Looks like you using get attributes there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25598824/2987273 for example

Comment: aha . Ok thanks.  When I use this code here  String some = (String) model.asMap().get("some");   Is there any danger of null pointer exception ?  could model be null ? What happens if flash attribute some is not set.

Comment: The Model won't be null - its gonna be injected by the framework.   what happens when some flash attributes are set and others aren't is your responsibility - you'll have to check for null values here.